# Gradient fill SVG after button click on HTML page

Tags: css, svg, colors, fill

Is possible to fill SVG by gradient colors after a button is clicked on the page? I read a lot of articles here, but none helped me. I need the gradient colors only in css (The best option).

Here's an example where I need to apply for "metalic colors" - http://web-stranky.org/pro_dementa/

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I don't believe you can use CSS gradients for SVG fills.

Comment: Just making grammatical and tying to the notion of this all happening on an html page.

Answer (score 0):

Svg yet not support CSS3 gradient property, although you can fill gradient in svg by defining gradient in svg and using fill property to attain gradient fill in svg.

```
<svg height="150" width="400">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>
```

for more details 
http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp

Comment: Thanks. I hope that this will help me.